# The OAuth client was not found. google login api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-signin

I want to use google-login api in my application but I have 2 different errors for it.

```
 1)Google login button is not rendering properly(Only render sometimes).
 2)when my button shows up i got "The OAuth client was not found." on click in popup window.
```

My credentials for google login api are

```
Client ID   :---> YOUR_CLIENT_ID
Client secret   :--->voMrsqhFNBtnh5FUvqy-jorI
Redirect URIs   :---->http://localhost:3000/
JavaScript origins :--->    http://localhost:3000/
```

I already changed my Project name many times.but it shows me the same error.

My HTML page is as under.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Scripts/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/github-fork.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bb-login.css">

<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com" 
       >

</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div class="header"></div>

    <div id="content" class="container">
            <script src="../Scripts/Vendor/requirejs/require.js" data-main="../Scripts/config.js"></script>
        </div>
  </div>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=start" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">  
  function start() {
    alert("inside start auth");
      gapi.load('auth2', function() {
      var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        alert(auth2);
      });
      if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
        alert("inside profile");
  var profile = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
}
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

and I am adding my `<div class="g-signin2"></div>` in different template for backbone.js.

what is the problem I have?

Answer (score -1):

The problem you are having, is that google API fails to see you as a registered client.

Google twitter and many more uses nowadays OAuth 2.0, which means you have to be a registered and known client to the platform before using it's API.

In your case, google is not recognizing you as an active client, thus:

```
"The OAuth client was not found."
```

Make sure you are REGISTERED and acknowledged by google and that ALL the credentials are right.